# How to add a coroutine/task to the loop from a 'blocking function' already running in a loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Hopefully the following code explains what I want to do better than the question title.

```
import asyncio
import time

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    @property
    def number(self):
        # Somehow need to run get_number() in the loop.
        number = self.get_number()
        return number
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def get_number(self):
        yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, self.num)
        return self.num


@asyncio.coroutine
def runner(num):
    print("getting Foo({})".format(num))
    foo = Foo(num)
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("accessing number property of Foo({})".format(num))
    number = foo.number
    print("Foo({}) number is {}".format(num, number))


tasks = [
    asyncio.async(runner(3)),
    asyncio.async(runner(1)),
    ]
go = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

I can't work out what to do in the `number` function, where the comment is. I've tried all sorts of things, but in reality I've just "been throwing **** at the wall and hoping something sticks".

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531380/using-property-decorator-with-asyncio-coroutine-without-doing-yield-from-possi). I want to access the property without doing a `yield from`, as I need to access the property from a template (eg mako), and having `yield from` written everywhere is not ideal (probably not even possible considering mako is probably blocking). In a perfect world, I would have all of this running with a [reify decorator](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid//en/latest/api/decorator.html).

If I wanted to use `yield from`, the code would be quite simple.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    @property
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def number(self):
        yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, self.num)
        return self.num


@asyncio.coroutine
def runner(num):
    print("getting Foo({})".format(num))
    foo = Foo(num)
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("accessing number property of Foo({})".format(num))
    number = yield from foo.number
    print("Foo({}) number is {}".format(num, number))

#getting Foo(3)
#getting Foo(1)
#accessing number property of Foo(3)
#accessing number property of Foo(1)
#Foo(1) number is 1
#Foo(3) number is 3
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29126866/3800244) on the topic, but I can't see how adding done callbacks will work with my workflow.

Comment: Sorry, you are asking for impossible thing.
There is no way to get a value from coroutine without `yield from`.

Comment: Where I have the comment `# Somehow need to run get_number() in the loop.` is where I am hoping to create a future task and put that into the loop, thus suspending the current function - I just don't know how to do it. So for example change `number = self.get_number()` to `number = loop.create_task(self.get_number())`. Is that possible or not?

Comment: @neRok The only way to suspend a currently running function is to use `yield from`, which means it has to be a coroutine. You can add a task to the event loop use `loop.create_task(self.get_number())`, like you suggested, but that task won't actually execute until the method that's actually calling `create_task` gives control back to the event loop, either by returning or making a call that uses `yield from`. Integrating `asyncio`-based code into synchronous code just isn't going to work the way you're hoping.

Comment: @neRok There are ways to do some level of integration between synchronous and `asyncio`-based code, just not quite the way you're trying to do it: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25299887/2073595 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/30155138/2073595.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is impossible because when you are in your main thread (where you want to call `foo.number` without the yield from, you need to explicitly give back control to the main loop. This is exactly what `yield from` does.

Without that, you need to run *the function that call foo.number* in a separate thread that would be able to block (no yield from) and wait for the result of `get_number` without blocking the main loop

Answer (score 0):

From your blocking function instead of calculated value you shall return `asyncio.Future`:

```
return loop.create_task(self.get_number())
```

When you get this in your async `runner` you can wait for result like this:

```
number = await foo.number
```

Full test case:

```
def test_future():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def target(x: int) -> int:
        loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 0.1)
        return x + 1

    def intermediate(x: int) -> asyncio.Future:
        return loop.create_task(target(x))

    async def main():
        future = intermediate(5)
        logger.debug('intermediate future = %r', future)
        value = await future
        assert value == 6

    try:
        loop.create_task(main())
        loop.call_later(0.5, loop.stop)
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.close()
```